# AWS Glue NameError: name 'DynamicFrame' is not defined

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

I'm trying to convert a dataframe to a Dynamic Frame using the `toDF` and `fromDF` functions (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame.html#aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame-fromDF) as per the below code snippet:

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

## @params: [JOB_NAME]
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)
## @type: DataSource
## @args: [database = "test-3", table_name = "test", transformation_ctx = "datasource0"]
## @return: datasource0
## @inputs: []
datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "test-3", table_name = "test", transformation_ctx = "datasource0")


foo = datasource0.toDF()
bar = DynamicFrame.fromDF(foo, glueContext, "bar")
```

However, I'm getting an error on the line:

```
bar = DynamicFrame.fromDF(foo, glueContext, "bar")
```

The error says:

```
NameError: name 'DynamicFrame' is not defined
```

I've tried the usual googling to no avail, I can't see what I've done wrong from other examples. Does anyone know why I'm getting this error and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
```

Import DynamicFrame

Comment: This import did not solve my issue, same error remains.

Answer (score 2):

You need to import the `DynamicFrame` class from `awsglue.dynamicframe` module:

```
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
```

There are lot of things missing in the examples provided with the AWS Glue ETL documentation.

However, you can refer to the following GitHub repository which contains lots of examples for performing basic tasks with Glue ETL:

[AWS Glue samples](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-glue-samples)